# Returning a nested dictionary within another dictionary with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a little problem with creating a complex Linq query. I have the following tables:

```
Activities
----------

- Date : DateTime
- ProjectId : int

Projects
--------

- ProjectId
- ProjectNumber
```

I need  to construct a query that returns a dictionary with the distinct years within the Activities table as keys. The value should be another dictionary containing all distinct months within the current distinct year as keys and then for each distinct month, I need a list of strings containing all the project numbers for that month.

So I would end up with something like this:

```
- 2014 //First distinct year
    - 1 //January
        - Contoso-2014-01 //Project number
    - 3 //March
        - IBM-2014-06 //Project number
- 2016 //Second distinct year
    - 4 //April
        - HP-2016-02 //Project number
```

Basically, we would have a dictionary containing two keys: 2014 and 2016
The values for the key 2014 would be a Dictionary with two KeyValuePairs. One with the key 1 and another with the key 3. Key 1 would have a list of strings as it's values containing the project number "Contoso-2014-01" and key 3 would contain "IBM-2014-06". And so on...

So now to my question: Is it even possible to query a database and get a return type structure like this? If yes, how can I achieve this?

Comment: for Ling2Sql you can use simple query: from x in 
(
 from a in Activities join p in Projects on a.ProjectId equals p.ProjectId
 select new {a.Date, p.ProjectNumber}
)
group x.ProjectNumber by new { x.Date.Year, x.Date.Month }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you have classes such as these

```
public class Activities
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public Project Project { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    public string ProjectNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Then I think this should work

```
public static void GetData()
{
    var mainDic = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, List<string>>>();
    List<Activities> acts = new List<Activities>(); // Your database context.

    acts.Select(x => x.Date.Year).Distinct().ToList().ForEach(
        year => 
        {
            var yearlyDic = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
            acts.Where(x => x.Date.Year == year).Select(x => x.Date.Month).Distinct().ToList().ForEach(
                month => 
                {
                    var projects = acts.Where(x => x.Date.Year == year && x.Date.Month == month)
                    .Select(x => x.Project.ProjectNumber).ToList();

                    yearlyDic.Add(month, projects);
                });

            mainDic.Add(year, yearlyDic);
        });
}
```

Comment: I didn't know you could write completely new statements INSIDE linq queries but this is exactly what I meant. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using SQL Server.. Here filtering Year part and Month part in the db query itself.

```
select YEAR(ac.[Date]) as projectYear, MONTH(ac.[Date]) as projectMonth ,pr.ProjectNumber Info from Activities ac join Projects pr on ac.ProjectId=pr.ProjectId


class ProjectActivity
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public string ProjectNumber { get; set; }

    public static List<ProjectActivity> GetProjectActivities()
    { 
       //You can use above query and construct the list.
        var sampleProjectActivities = new List<ProjectActivity>();

        var projActivitySamp1 = new ProjectActivity()
        {
            Year = 2014,
            Month = 1,
            ProjectNumber = "Contoso-2014-01"
        };

        sampleProjectActivities.Add(projActivitySamp1);

        var projActivitySamp2 = new ProjectActivity()
        {
            Year = 2014,
            Month = 3,
            ProjectNumber = "Contoso-2014-03"
        };

        sampleProjectActivities.Add(projActivitySamp2);

        var projActivitySamp3 = new ProjectActivity()
        {
            Year = 2016,
            Month = 4,
            ProjectNumber = "HP-2016-02"
        };

        sampleProjectActivities.Add(projActivitySamp3);

        var projActivitySamp4 = new ProjectActivity()
        {
            Year = 2016,
            Month = 4,
            ProjectNumber = "AnotherHP-2016-04"
        };

        sampleProjectActivities.Add(projActivitySamp4);

        return sampleProjectActivities;
    }
}
```

And call the code like this

```
        var sampleProjectActivities = ProjectActivity.GetProjectActivities();

        var result = sampleProjectActivities.GroupBy(projectActivity => projectActivity.Year)
            .ToDictionary(k => k.Key,
                v =>
                {
                    return v.GroupBy(val => val.Month).ToDictionary(a => a.Key, b => b.Select(x => x.ProjectNumber).ToArray());

                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your classes are named as you have mentioned (in the tables)..
This lambda should give you the dictionary that you need..

```
        var dictionary = acts.GroupBy(activity => activity.Date.Year) // gives you year-wise groups
                               .ToDictionary(yearGroup => yearGroup.Key,
                                             yearGroup => yearGroup.ToDictionary(activity => activity.Date.Month, // gives you month-wise groups
                                                                                 activity => yearGroup.Where(a => a.Date.Month == activity.Date.Month)
                                                                                                      .Select(a => a.Project.ProjectNumber)
                                                                                                      .ToList() // all the project numbers under this year and month
                                                                                ));
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the most straight-forward way to go:

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>> query =
(
    from a in activities
    join p in projects on a.ProjectId equals p.ProjectId
    group new
    {
        a.Date.Month,
        p.ProjectNumber,
    } by a.Date.Year into gaps
    select new
    {
        gaps.Key,
        Value = gaps.ToDictionary(x => x.Month, x => x.ProjectNumber),
    }
).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```